# Jackson: Object to String via writeValueAsString: NPE

Tags: java, json, jackson

Im attempting to convert a Java Object into JSON using the Jackson parser. The original object comes to me via protobuf and contains some @annotations specific to Jackson.

When I call `String jsonView = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(values);`

I get this exception. The object doesn't contain any recursive values so I'm not clear why Im seeing this error (or even this code path).

ObjectMapper is configured with: `objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);` (although removing it doesn't seem to change anything)

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.ResolvedRecursiveType.equals(ResolvedRecursiveType.java:103)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings$AsKey.equals(TypeBindings.java:458)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:940)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.LRUMap.get(LRUMap.java:68)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1211)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:1384)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1154)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._resolveSuperInterfaces(TypeFactory.java:1298)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1243)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1150)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._resolveSuperInterfaces(TypeFactory.java:1298)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1247)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1150)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:618)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.constructType(MapperConfig.java:290)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.introspectClassAnnotations(MapperConfig.java:320)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.removeIgnorableTypes(BeanSerializerFactory.java:714)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.findBeanProperties(BeanSerializerFactory.java:573)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.constructBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:390)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.findBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:273)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:225)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:159)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1272)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1243)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:535)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.resolve(BeanSerializerBase.java:332)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.SerializerCache.addAndResolveNonTypedSerializer(SerializerCache.java:174)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1254)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:535)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.resolve(BeanSerializerBase.java:332)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.SerializerCache.addAndResolveNonTypedSerializer(SerializerCache.java:174)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1254)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:535)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.resolve(BeanSerializerBase.java:332)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.SerializerCache.addAndResolveNonTypedSerializer(SerializerCache.java:197)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1233)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:499)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:697)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:270)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3672)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3048)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in latest versions (see 2.8.1 or above):
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1302